# A kids book called Will O' The Wisp or similar?

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

Does anyone recall a book called something like *Will of the Wisp* or simlar?
It was about these Fairy or Elf like creatures that lived on Wortleberries, who had to flee their home due to pollution or something similar. They were menaced by Padfoot, had to get a ride with a squirrel and things similar to that.

All I can think of was that it had a green cover and we cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it and do you have an idea of when it might have been written (roughly the year maybe)?

Comment: https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/39129/ - Is this you?

Comment: That wasn't me but was the same book from the look of it!

Comment: Read it in late 60s, early seventies was when I read it. I had a hunch the autor's name might have been Rochelle something or something Rochelle, but not sure and unable to find on google.

Answer (score 7):

My wife got sick of me grumbling and went sleuthing and worked it all out: Thanks for inspiring us...!

The title was *[The Last of The Wispies](https://www.worldofrarebooks.com/the-last-of-the-wispies-by-glyn-frewer.html)* by Glyn Frewer.

[Story summary](http://forums.abebooks.de/discussions/AbeBookscom_BookSleuthreg/Childrens/Hardcover_book_including_Hobyahs_story/abesleuthcom/15686.1?redirCnt=1)

> The Wispies had once been very numerous,but now only Will o' the Wisp and Granfer were left-and perhaps Will's brother Jack o' Lantern, who had left home a thousand years or so before. The Wispies were tiny creatures, immensly long-lived, and eating nothing but bog-whortle-berries. So when whortleberry bushes in Fenmarsh died, Will had to set out on his dangerous journey through the Twilight World in search of more food. He was accompanied by his friend Squiff, the squirrel, and their adventures with the Padfoot, the Redcap, the Hobyahs, the Badger, Billy Blind and other good and evil creatures make an exciting and unusual story."

Comment: You can accept your own answer 48 hours after it was asked, and we highly encourage you to do so. And welcome to the site.

Comment: Hah... your current reputation score confused me until I clicked through. You've been here longer than I thought. But I am glad you found this one.

Comment: Lord, I remember this...scared the cr*p out of me at the time.